OpenPGP port (1194) can't be opened. OpenVPN-AS
I installed Openvpn-As on my Ubuntu 20.04 server and used default settings for everything. I tried connecting to my VPN using the OpenVPN client on mobile locally and it works with no issues.
I was now trying from the outside. I enabled port forwarding on my router and opened the following ports: 943, 443, 1194, but it did not work. It kept connecting until a time-out message appeared. I used a port checker service (https://portchecker.co/) and it shows that 1194 is still the only closed port I need.
Then I used ufw to enable each port individually and reload it afterward, but it didn't solve the issue. I tested that I can externally connect to the server with SSH (22) and had no trouble with that, so my server is reachable at least.
Here are some screenshots of my Port Forwarding configuration and ufw.
Results of ufw status :

Port Forwarding configuration:

Checking for HTTPS port:

Checking for 943 port:

Checking for OpenPGP port:

Used Router = ZTE ZXHN F680

Assuming you mean "OpenVPN port" 1194, is your port checking service actually checking for UDP connectivity? 1194 is for UDP connections and 943 for TCP.
